# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ajax, fetch

Estoy intentando sacar información por un método `fetch`, pero al actualizar la página me salta el error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Parece que algo no funciona en el parametro de la función `listadoUsuarios().
Código JS:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
var load = document.querySelector('#load');

getUsuarios()
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(users => {
    listadoUsuarios(users.data);
});

function getUsuarios(){
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
function listadoUsuarios(usuarios){
    usuarios.map((user , i) => {
        let nombre = document.createElement('h2');
        nombre.innerHTML = `${i} - ${user.name}, ${user.username}`;
        div.appendChild(nombre);
        load.style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

Html:

```
<body>
    <h1>Listado de usuarios</h1>
    <div id="usuarios">
       <p id="load">Cargando...</p> 
    </div>
    <script src="Fetch.js"></script>
</body>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que la forma en la que se llama a la API puede estar provocando el mensaje de TypeError, **Fetch** necesita configuración *async*:

```
function getUsuarios(){
          fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
              headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json',
              }
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
              listadoUsuarios(res);// la respuesta ya regresó
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
          })
      }
```

Una vez que la respuesta ya regresó, ya se puede llamar a la función que la maneja (handler), en este caso `listadoUsuarios(usuarios)`:

```
function listadoUsuarios(usuarios){
       
          usuarios.map((user , i) => {
              let nombre = document.createElement('h2');
              nombre.textContent = `${i} - ${user.name}, ${user.username}`;
              div.appendChild(nombre);
              load.style.display = 'none';
          });
      }
```

Ahora, es recomendable usar la propiedad **textContext**, en vez de **innerHTML**.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Finalmente, tu script puede hacer la llamada a la función `getUsuarios()` al iniciar la app, así como la configuraste, pero sin el código de fetch:

```
function listadoUsuarios(usuarios){
       
          usuarios.map((user , i) => {
              let nombre = document.createElement('h2');
              nombre.textContent = `${i} - ${user.name}, ${user.username}`;
              div.appendChild(nombre);
              load.style.display = 'none';
          });
      }

      function getUsuarios(){
          fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
              headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json',
              }
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
              listadoUsuarios(res);
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
          })
      }
      getUsuarios();
```

Saludos