# ¿Cómo puedo transformar un json desde fetch en array con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, array, fetch

Estoy tratando de hacer una paginación de varias maneras distintas y no doy con ello... El problema es que obtengo un json desde la  base de datos y no logro sacarlo de ahí correctamente para utilizarlo. Logro pasarlo a una  variable externa  a la función, pero una  vez ahí ni siquiera me muestra la propiedad `.length`una vez fuera... Me dice que su tamaño es 0, cosa  que  es mentira porque si lo imprimo en consola el array entero sí me aparece y me  pone length: 3, como ves a continuación:

```
arrayPersonas después de llamar a la funcion:[] 
0: {idpersona: "1", nombre: "Nombre", apellidos: "Apellidos", sexo: "Masculino"}
1: {idpersona: "2", nombre: "Nombre", apellidos: "Apellidos", sexo: "Femenino"}
2: {idpersona: "3", nombre: "Facundo", apellidos: "El De Las Pipas", sexo: "Masculino"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Pero cuando escribo `arrayPersonas.length` me pone 0 y por  eso no logro acceder... Os  muestro el código:

```
var arrayPersonas = Array();
const mostrarPersonasPaginacion = () => {
    var url = "./ejecutarConsultas.php";

    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(lista_de_personas => {
        console.log("lista_de_personas dentro del fetch:",lista_de_personas);
        console.log("Tamaño de lista_de_personas dentro del fetch:",lista_de_personas.length);
        console.log("Tratando de acceder lista_de_personas con .nombre dentro del fetch:",lista_de_personas[2].nombre);
        console.log("Tratando de acceder lista_de_personas con ['nombre'] dentro del fetch:",lista_de_personas[2]['nombre']);
        console.log("Tipo de lista_de_personas dentro del fetch:",typeof(lista_de_personas));
        for (let i = 0; i < lista_de_personas.length; i++) {
            arrayPersonas[i] = lista_de_personas[i];
            //console.log(arrayPersonas[i]);
        }
        console.log("arrayPersonas dentro del fetch:",arrayPersonas);
        console.log("Tamaño de arrayPersonas dentro del fetch:",arrayPersonas.length);
        console.log("Tratando de acceder arrayPersonas con .nombre dentro del fetch:",arrayPersonas[2].nombre);
        console.log("Tratando de acceder arrayPersonas con ['nombre'] dentro del fetch:",arrayPersonas[2]['nombre']);
        console.log("Tipo de arrayPersonas dentro del fetch:",typeof(arrayPersonas));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("¡Error!", error);
    })
    console.log("arrayPersonas dentro de la función y fuera del fetch:",arrayPersonas);
    console.log("Tamaño de arrayPersonas dentro de la función y fuera del fetch:",arrayPersonas.length);
    //console.log("Tratando de acceder arrayPersonas con .nombre dentro de la función y fuera del fetch:",arrayPersonas[2].nombre);
    //console.log("Tratando de acceder arrayPersonas con ['nombre'] dentro de la función y fuera del fetch:",arrayPersonas[2]['nombre']);
    console.log("Tipo de arrayPersonas dentro de la función y fuera del fetch:",typeof(arrayPersonas));
}

mostrarPersonasPaginacion();
console.log("arrayPersonas después de llamar a la funcion:",arrayPersonas);
console.log("Tamaño de arrayPersonas después de llamar a la funcion:",arrayPersonas.length);
//console.log("Tratando de acceder arrayPersonas con .nombre dentro de la función y fuera del fetch:",arrayPersonas[2].nombre);
//console.log("Tratando de acceder arrayPersonas con ['nombre'] dentro de la función y fuera del fetch:",arrayPersonas[2]['nombre']);
console.log("Tipo de arrayPersonas después de llamar a  la función:",typeof(arrayPersonas));
```

Llevo unos cuantos  días probando muchas formas... Me falla también si lo hago con return y llamando a la función como valor de la variable arrayPersonas (encuyo  caso, me dice `undefined`. También he probado en vez  de `var arrayPersonas = Array();` cambiándolo por `var arrayPersonas = [];` con el mismo resultado que os he comentado al principio.

En cuanto al  tipo, todas  pone  que son `Object`. La que viene desde el fetch, sí lo es, que que  es  un Json. Pero lo  otro precisamente la intención es  transformarla en array. De hecho, tanto la  `lista_de_personas` como el `arrayPersonas` cuando los pongo por  consola se muestran así:

```
lista_de_personas dentro del fetch: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {idpersona: "1", nombre: "Nombre", apellidos: "Apellidos", sexo: "Masculino"}1: {idpersona: "2", nombre: "Nombre", apellidos: "Apellidos", sexo: "Femenino"}2: {idpersona: "3", nombre: "Facundo", apellidos: "El De Las Pipas", sexo: "Masculino"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

Como digo, la  del arrayPersonas, aún dentro del fetch, me lo muestra  igual. Pero fuera, lo muestra como he  puesto arriba cuando mencionaba  que sí me mostraba la  propiedad `.length`. Por tanto, sí hay diferencia  entre el fetch y fuera del mismo o de la  función. Y es lo que  no logro entender... Por eso quería  pasarlo a array pero bien, que me reconozca en este caso su propiedad .length 3... De lo contrario, ¿cómo va a funcionarme la  paginación si no sé cuántas personas hay  en total?

Espero que se entienda claro...
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: vos estas probando esto localmente? me refiero si tu server es localhost.

Comment: Sí, efectivamente. Todo en local, incluida la base de datos... Con Xampp. ¿Cambia mucho el resultado?

Comment: la verdad que no. Solo preguntaba para ver si yo podia conectarme a tu API para probar, porque todavia no me queda claro cual es la respuesta original de tu API (antes de que lo conviertas a Array)

Comment: Ok, como habías  preguntado pensé  que igual según qué servidor local use podría dar fallos  o algo así. :D

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [utilizar variable fuera del fetch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290825/utilizar-variable-fuera-del-fetch)

Comment: ¡Hola, @Mauricio-Contreras! Creo que sí, pero no estoy familiarizado con **async-await** y me cuesta entenderlo. Aunque  el aspecto es bastante sencillo... Pero creo que  sí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código esta bien estructurado y depurado, pero considera que **fetch** es **asyncronous**,  esto es, que espera un evento de regreso, en este caso, la respuesta de la API.

Debido a las reglas de ejecución de JS, el programa llama primero a `mostrarPersonasPaginacion()`, pero *fetch* aún no regresa, por eso *no se tienen los datos en ese momento* (el `console.log` del enclosing scope lo demuestra).

Luego, *fetch* ya completó la operación **async**, regresa el resultado de una **promesa** y nos deja ver estos resultados, dentro de `then`. (el `console.log` del scope `then`lo demuestra)

Lo más práctico en tu caso, es continuar con la ejecución de tu programa dentro del `then` donde está la respuesta, entonces puedes llamar primero a la función `mostrarPersonasPaginacion()`.

> Yo cambiaría el nombre de `mostrarPersonasPaginacion()` por `cargarDatosDePaginacion()`.

Después, manejas la respuesta de la promesa dentro de la secuencia `then`, con otra función de continuación:

```
.then(lista_de_personas => {
        console.log(lista_de_personas);
         //ya regreso la respuesta, callback
        //aqui llamas tu funcion de continuacion
        //logica de paginacion
        continuationFn(lista_de_personas);
       
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("¡Error!", error);
    })
```

La sugerencia es analizar a los conceptos de **Event Driven Programming, Promises y async/await** para JS. Dependiendo del estilo, se manejan diferentes patrones de codificación de eventos async, donde puedes estructurar tu código de otra forma.

[Problemas con promesas asycn code](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384069/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined/384080#384080)
[Promesas async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549364/how-to-run-2-lines-of-javascript-in-sequence-async-promises-callbacks)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!  ¿Y  la  función de continuación estaría **fuera** de `cargarDatosDePaginación()` (me gusta el nombre, el otro era porque la intención inicial era hacerlo todo enero ahí mismo pero no funcionaba anterior y siguiente) o anidada dentro de la misma función pero ya fuera del **fetch**? Deduzco que una función aparte, pero pregunto por si acaso... En cuanto a lo de **async/await** tendré que verlo bien, porque parece buena  opción y se ahorra algo de  código, pero de momento me quedo con **fetch**.

Comment: @Diego la función es aparte, puedes declararla fuera de la función async mostrarPersonasPaginacion(), pero debes llamarla dentro de fetch, como te indique en el ejemplo. Puedes declararla dentro de fectch, pero se vera muy abultado el código. Yo también prefiero esta configuración, asi no se pierde el concepto del estilo de continuación, pero con async/await el codigo queda escrito en un estilo más funcional. Si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor da click en aceptar. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo pruebo y te confirmo si me va  tan bien.:) Que tiene toda la pinta  de que  sí y está muy bien explicado. No me deja poner tu nick... se  borra al  guardar... A  ver ahora... @g.4

Comment: @Diego, espero que vaya bien!!!, mira ya hay otra respuesta con respecto a cómo puedes continuar en la nueva función con el manejo del objeto json, saludos.

Comment: ¡Hola, @g.4! Finalmente, tu  solución, aunque sigo  dependiendo de la función  de  continuación y por tanto el resto de funciones las he metido dentro de la dependiente, salvo botón adelante y atrás, que forzosamente lo tenía  que poner  fuera, me ha servido.y he entendido suficientemente claro... ¡Muchas  gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Una vez que recibe la respuesta podes llamar la función que utilizas para manipular tu array de objetos.

Abri una pestaña nueva y podes probarlo en la consola del Chrome:

```javascript
let personasArray = []
function looping(personasDatos){
    for(let i =0; i < personasDatos.length; i++){
    console.log(personasDatos[i])
  }
}
function doFetch(URL){
    fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    //aqui llamas a la funcion looping para pasarle la respuesta del fetch
    .then(lista_de_personas => {
        //spred operator para copiar el array. Asi no hace falta que 
        //vuelvas a hacer otro fetch
        personasArray = [...lista_de_personas.data]
      looping(lista_de_personas.data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message)) 
}
doFetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
```

### Más información acerca del [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Dé donde sacas lo de `hastable`? El OP recibe un `Array` de objetos. ¿Para qué usar `Object.keys` cuando un bucle `for` sencillo es suficiente para iterar el `Array`? El problema del OP no es iterar el `Array`, sino cuándo iterarlo, ya que pretende hacerlo de forma síncrona después de una llamada asíncrona. Revisa tu respuesta porque tiene defectos. Saludos

Comment: ¡Hola, @jdromero88! No he llegado a entender bien la  parte de la  constante, ni dónde crearla... Porque  si la creo dentro del fetch y luego  la necesito usar de otra forma, desde alguna otra función  externa, ya está el lío... También es verdad quemi nivel no  es muy alto... Pero la idea  en sí creo que la entiendo. No  obstante, creo que no hasta el momento sólo me ha servido la de @g.4 (que, aunque  también dependo de la segunda función, creo que lo he entendido mejor y he podido realizarlo... ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @DiegoGrande disculpame, ahora mejore mi respuesta. Copiando el array dentro del fetch asi lo tendrias en una variable para poder manipularlo despues donde lo necesites.